# Is it better to Learn first WCF 3.5 the move to WCF 4.0 for beginners?

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF and Dot Net 4.0. Which is the better learning path shall I start Learning WCF 3.5 then move to WCF 4.0 or Start WCF 4.0 directly.

Please Advise

Answer (score 2):

These are two different versions of the same thing. They're not that different. Just start learning WCF.

Answer (score 1):

I were you, I would go for learning the .NET 4.0 because its newer. I assume the new version has support for the old stuff, but If you use the 3.5 you may be missing som feautures that is supported in the 4.0.